# Generating tables from Entities with EclipseLink does nothing

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, entities

I'm trying to generate entities from a SQL Server database and generating said tables onto a MySQL database. I successfully generated the entities with JPA tools, and I now have entities similar to this one:

```
@Entity
//It was originally the @Table annotation, I changed it just to see if
//it would work like this
@TableGenerator(name="AGENCY",schema="amex_digital_test_dev")
@NamedQuery(name="Agency.findAll", query="SELECT a FROM Agency a")
public class Agency implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
private int IDAgency;

@Column(name="Channel_Code")
private String channel_Code;

@Column(name="CodiceOAM")
private String codiceOAM;

@Column(name="DistributionList")
private String distributionList;

@Column(name="IsSimpleSignature")
private boolean isSimpleSignature;

@Column(name="Name", nullable=false)
private String name;

public Agency() {
}

public int getIDAgency() {
    return this.IDAgency;
}

public void setIDAgency(int IDAgency) {
    this.IDAgency = IDAgency;
}

public String getChannel_Code() {
    return this.channel_Code;
}

public void setChannel_Code(String channel_Code) {
    this.channel_Code = channel_Code;
}

public String getCodiceOAM() {
    return this.codiceOAM;
}

public void setCodiceOAM(String codiceOAM) {
    this.codiceOAM = codiceOAM;
}

public String getDistributionList() {
    return this.distributionList;
}

public void setDistributionList(String distributionList) {
    this.distributionList = distributionList;
}

public boolean getIsSimpleSignature() {
    return this.isSimpleSignature;
}

public void setIsSimpleSignature(boolean isSimpleSignature) {
    this.isSimpleSignature = isSimpleSignature;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

 }
```

My persistence.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns   /persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="JPAAmex" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.Agency</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.AgencyRegionView</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.Agent</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.AgentAgencyRegionAndSubRegionRel</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.AgentAgencyRegionAndSubRegionRelBackUp</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.AgentGroup</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.AgentsInfo</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.AmexStatoPriorita</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.AmexXEROXField</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.AmexXEROXSection</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.Application</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.ApplicationField</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.ApplicationFieldBk</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.ApplicationFieldBkWithAttachGood</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.ApplicationFieldStatus</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.ApplicationFieldTemplate</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.ApplicationFieldTemplateFixedValue</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.ApplicationOfferAndRegionRel</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.ApplicationOfferSuppBaseRel</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.ApplicationPacakge</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.ApplicationPackageArkDap</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.ApplicationProductOffer</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.ApplicationSection</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.ApplicationSectionPdf</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.ApplicationSectionTemplate</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.ApplicationSignaturePDF</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.ApplicationStatus</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.ApplicationTemplate</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.ApplicationTemplateBackUp</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.ApplicationTrace</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.AreaRegion</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.AreaSubRegion</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.AreamanagerAgent</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.BankList</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.BankList_old</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.BankList_two</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.Cab</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.CabList</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.CabList_old</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.CervedCredenzial</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.Comuni</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.Comuni_bck_20181227</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.Comuni_bck_old</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.ConfigurazioneSegnalazione</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.Cordinate_Firma_Agente</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.Crif</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.DboApplicationPacakge</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.ErrorSqlTrace</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.InternationalTelPrefix</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.Level_Rule</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.Nazionalita</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.NazioniIso</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.New</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.SBS_OfferList</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.SectionStatus</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.SegnalazioneApplicationSection</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.Segnalazioni</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.StorageCervedVisure</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.Sysdiagram</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.Teamleader_AM</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.TempSignersInfo</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.TemplateAppkeyStore</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.TipologiaSegnalazione</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.TokenPushService</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.UsedPassword</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.VersionMobile</class>
    <class>com.olsa.amex.entities.VisureType</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://rmarjboss-001c.customer.olsa:3306/amex_digital_test_dev"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="usrmysql"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="******"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
        <property name="eclipselink.composite-unit.member" value="true"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.MySQLPlatform"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
        <property name="eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="create.sql"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.deploy-on-startup" value="true" />
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I start the process by going onto JPA Tools --> Generate Tables from Entities, and a windows pops up:

[image: window]

I click on "Finish", and then the console shows up, it gives no errors, but it doesn't do anything:

```
 apr 03, 2019 2:36:11 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
 INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
name: JPAAmex
...]
 apr 03, 2019 2:36:11 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
 INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}
 apr 03, 2019 2:36:11 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
 INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
apr 03, 2019 2:36:11 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
 INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
 apr 03, 2019 2:36:11 PM      org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProvi     derImpl configure
 WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for      production use!)
 apr 03, 2019 2:36:11 PM      org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProvi     derImpl buildCreator
 INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL      [jdbc:mysql://rmarjboss-001c.customer.olsa:3306     /amex_digital_test_dev?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8]
 apr 03, 2019 2:36:11 PM      org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProvi     derImpl buildCreator
 INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=usrmysql,      password=****}
 apr 03, 2019 2:36:11 PM      org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProvi     derImpl buildCreator
 INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
 apr 03, 2019 2:36:11 PM      org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProvi     derImpl$PooledConnections <init>
 INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
 Wed Apr 03 14:36:11 CEST 2019 WARN: Establishing SSL connection           without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to      MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be      established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with      existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is      set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting      useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server      certificate verification.
 apr 03, 2019 2:36:12 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
 INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
 apr 03, 2019 2:36:12 PM org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass      checkCompositeIdentifier
 WARN: HHH000038: Composite-id class does not override equals():      com.olsa.amex.entities.ApplicationTrace
 apr 03, 2019 2:36:12 PM org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass      checkCompositeIdentifier
 WARN: HHH000039: Composite-id class does not override hashCode():      com.olsa.amex.entities.ApplicationTrace
 apr 03, 2019 2:36:13 PM      org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator initiateService
 INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
 apr 03, 2019 2:36:13 PM      org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProvi     derImpl stop
 INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool      [jdbc:mysql://rmarjboss-001c.customer.olsa:3306     /amex_digital_test_dev?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8]
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? It would save me a lot of time to just generate tables like this. Thanks in advance for the help!

EDIT: Just adding one thing here: I am just using a JPA/Maven project

Comment: Don't show password. Better change it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to generate DB by running standalone java app..

```
public static void main(String...args){
    EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPAAmex").createEntityManager(); 
}
```